# Ключевое слово final

Tags: java

В исходниках `LibGDX`, в классе `Vector2` есть метод `dst`, который определяет расстояние между векторами. [Vector2.java](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.java)
Вот он:

```
public float dst (float x, float y) {
    final float x_d = x - this.x;
    final float y_d = y - this.y;
    return (float)Math.sqrt(x_d * x_d + y_d * y_d);
}
```

В нем промежуточные переменные `x_d`, `y_d` объявлены как `final`. Зачем? Чем бы это отличалось от этого:

```
public float dst (float x, float y) {
    float x_d = x - this.x;
    float y_d = y - this.y;
    return (float)Math.sqrt(x_d * x_d + y_d * y_d);
}
```

В этом есть какая то особая магия?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`final` — прежде всего *защита от самого себя*.

Дело в том, что хорошие компиляторы «умнее» людей. Компилятор может легко пробежаться по коду и выяснить, изменяется ли переменная в методе, и сам применить нужные оптимизации, если считает нужным. Время «подсказок компилятору» на нормальных платформах прошло.

А вот защититься от собственных глупых ошибок — например, чтобы случайно не изменить переменную, которую вовсе не нужно менять — хорошая идея. Если вы случайно измените `final`-переменную, компилятор немедленно подскажет вам об этом.

Вы можете смотреть на `final` как на часть декларации типа. Можно было бы в принципе отказаться от type safety и использовать только тип `Object` в программе. Когда вы говорите, что переменная имеет тип `String`, вы намеренно ограничиваете себя: теперь вы можете присваивать объекту только `String`-значения, при попытке присвоить `int` компилятор укажет вам на ваш просчёт. Точно так же декларация `final` позволяет вам ограничить себя, запретить самому себе менять значение, чтобы защититься от ошибок.

Мне кажется, указывать наиболее *сильное* ограничение переменной по типу — хорошая привычка. Действительно, в данном конкретном коде константность переменной очевидна и без `final` и не приносит дополнительных дивидендов. Тем не менее, имеет смысл не задумываясь ставить `final` везде, где переменная не должна меняться, не отвлекаясь на то, как в данный момент реализован метод.

Answer (score 8):

Магия минимальная. После того, как переменная была объявлена с модификатором final, ее нельзя поменять (проще говоря - она константа). В больших кусках кода это может помочь (К примеру, переменная по ходу дела где то меняется, а найти не можем. Делаем ее final и компилятор подскажет).

Вот такой код уже не будет компилироваться

```
public float dst (float x, float y) {
    final float x_d = x - this.x;
    final float y_d = y - this.y;
    x_d = 2;
    return (float)Math.sqrt(x_d * x_d + y_d * y_d);
}
```

Есть ли смысл так писать? Это такой же вопрос как и делать ли все по умолчанию const в C++. Некоторые верят, что это даст подсказку компилятору и он сделает более быстрый код. Некоторым кажется, что так писать просто по феншую.

Мое мнение - в данном случае так писать нет никакого смысла.

P.S. ссылки

- [Когда стоит использовать модификатор final для переменных](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/java/1862508.flat)
- [Что дает нам final, кроме константности?](http://habrahabr.ru/qa/20344/)

Comment: Назначения final-а мне известно. Непонятно только зачем его использовать в данном случае.

Comment: некоторые люди думают, что они умнее компилятора и пытаются его перехитрить. А компилятор за это может наказать сильным проседанием производительности. Но в примере выше - это просто такой стиль.