# Как работает ключевое слово final?

Tags: java

> А ещё есть специальное ключевое слово final, и если оно присутствует в объявлении переменной, вам будет разрешено присвоить значение этой переменной только один раз и вы не сможете уже изменить это значение после.

Прочитал это в книге. Далее захожу в идею и пишу:

```
 public class Main {
    public static final String name = "Tom";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Выводится слово Tom.

Далее я изменяю в нашей константе name на значение Jerry:

```
public class Main {
    public static final String name = "Jerry";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

И вижу в консоли Jerry, а в книге написано "вам будет разрешено присвоить значение этой переменной ТОЛЬКО ОДИН РАЗ и вы НЕ сможете уже изменить это значение после". Можете разъяснить ситуацию, чтобы я понял в чём суть?

Comment: Это имеется ввиду в runtime(при выполнении одного цельного кода)

Comment: Кхе-кхе... эммм... даже и не знаю что сказать то :) - нет не минусую, хотя рука тянется к нагану :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изменения касаются рантайма, так нельзя сделать:

```
public class Main {
    public static final String name = "Jerry";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        name = "Tom";//here is Error
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Имеется ввиду, что в ходе выполнения программы Вы не сможете изменить.
Например:

```
  public class Main {
    public static final String name = "Tom";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        name = "Jhon"; // Error
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Тут более подробный ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/264033/Ключевое-слово-final?rq=1